# model.save doesn't when i change one attribute to false

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, model, attributes, required

I have a model Vote. Vote has an attribute vote_type. In my controller I do this

```
 @vote = Vote.fetch(1)
 logger.warn("current vote_type: #{@vote.vote_type}")
 @vote.vote_type = false 
 @vote.save
```

This doesn't throw any error but I see the following in my server

```
    Vote Columns (0.7ms)   SHOW FIELDS FROM `votes`
    current vote_type: true
    SQL (0.1ms)   BEGIN
    SQL (0.1ms)   ROLLBACK
```

I have no idea why it is rolling back. What am i doing wrong?

Comment: Try `@vote.save!` and it will tell you if it's a validation error.

Comment: Its throwing an error `Vote type can't be blank`. I think rails is substituting nil for false values but mysql would be expecting a 0. How can i handle this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the field can 'not have a value' - which is what false is - then remove the required => true from the original migration and recreate that table/db (or create a new migration that removes the required setting).

Comment: There was need for any migration, just removing the validates_presence_of did the trick. Thanx.

Comment: Just be careful: The rails validations and the SQL valdations are not (necessarily) connected so if you get them out of sync it can suck ;)

Answer (score 1):

A common issue with Rails is trying to 'validate_presence' of a boolean. That validation uses .blank? and false.blank => true. Therefore, to validate the presence of a boolean, use:

```
validates :vote_type, :inclusion => {:in => [true, false]}
```

Comment: Unfortunately i'm in rails version 2.3.5 and validates is present in versions > 3 :(

Comment: In Rails 2.3: validates_inclusion_of :vote_type, :in => [true, false]